# to send the selected object form a jface view to another jface view while navigating to it

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I have a jface tableviewer table in a jface view, user can click any row of the tableviewer table, on click the view must navigate to another view and also send selected row ID to the view navigated.
As of now I can navigate to another view successfully and also get the selected row ID with the code

```
viewer.getTable().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {  
@Override 
public void  handleEvent(Event e) {  
    try {  
       int selected = viewer.getTable().getSelectionIndex(); 
       String selection = viewer.getTable().getItem(selected).getText();       PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("E2E_tab_view.view5");  
    } 
    catch (PartInitException e1) {  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();  
  }  }  });
```

but unable to send this selected row ID to another view while navigation.
Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referring to the other view directly, you should utilize the [`ISelectionService`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ISelectionService.html) of workbench page.

In the first view, you set the table viewer to be the selection provider for its site:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

In the other view you register a selection listener on the [`IWorkbenchPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html):

```
getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(firstViewID, listener);
```

In your [listener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ISelectionListener.html) you can access the selected item using [IStructuredSelection](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/IStructuredSelection.html) interface:

```
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
    //Assuming structured selection from structured viewer
    IStructuredSelection structSel = (IStructuredSelection)selection;
    Object selElement = structSel.getFirstElement();
}
```

Comment: I just need to send the string value to the next view navigating. Can you help now.

Comment: @PramodiniRaju I updated my answer. There's really nothing more to do than that.